# Column not found in the database inspite of its existence

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have written a script in python in which I am trying  to access the Y1 column of the database. But the command line is giving me the error stating that column Y1 does not exist. But the column is present in the database. I have created the database using the SQLAlchemy library and now I am querying it on the other ATOM file using psycopg2 library (Just For The Sake Of Information).

```
import psycopg2
def search_data(X):
    cont=psycopg2.connect("dbname='DNA_RECORD1' user='postgres' 
    password='1364' host='localhost' port='5432'")
    curs=cont.cursor()
    curs.execute("SELECT location FROM data WHERE Y1=%s",(X,))
    curs.execute("SELECT holder_name FROM data WHERE Y1=%s",(X,))
    cont.close()

    search_data(9868)
```

Comment: Can you show the output of `DESCRIBE data;` command ?

Comment: db=SQLAlchemy(app)
class Data(db.Model):
    __tablename__="data"
    X=db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True,unique=True)
    Y=db.Column(db.Integer,unique=True)
    X1=db.Column(db.Integer,unique=True)
    Y1=db.Column(db.Integer,unique=True)
    location=db.Column(db.String(100))
    holder_name=db.Column(db.String(50))
    email=db.Column(db.String(50))

Comment: @AshrafulIslam here it is

Comment: that's not the database level description of the table, and doesn't prove that your table really have this field.

Comment: X=request.form["c1"]
        Y=request.form["c2"]
        X1=request.form["c3"]
        Y1=request.form["c4"]
        holder_name=request.form["hold_rec"]
        location=request.form["lo"]
        email=request.form["e"]

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers

Comment: I could see the column in my table (postgreSQL) @brunodesthuilliers

Comment: I have completed a part of it using SQLAlchemy library . But since i am unable to query the object using SQLAlchemy so i decided to set up a connection with that object on another file and then query it using psycopg2 library and then import it to the original file.

Comment: Wrap Y1 in quotes like this "SELECT location FROM data WHERE 'Y1' = 123"